# Segfault in templated subclass destructor

Tags: c++, g++

I'm working on a parser and I'm having trouble with a pesky segfault.

The parser returns a parsed variant which, in turn, returns the variant to be used for delivering the parsed result. The segfault occurs when deleting a pointer to the base class.

Here is my base class:

```
class ParsedVariant {

protected:
    ParsedVariant() {}

public:
    virtual ~ParsedVariant() {}

private:
    ParsedVariant(const ParsedVariant& other);
    ParsedVariant& operator= (const ParsedVariant& other);

public:
    virtual const std::string& getName() const=0;
    // Get the final variant.
    virtual Variant *getVariant()=0;

};
```

And here is the templated subclass:

```
template<typename S, class V> class ParsedScalar : public ParsedVariant {

public:
    ParsedScalar(const S& s, const std::string& n) : sval(s), name(n) {}
    ~ParsedScalar() {}

private:
    ParsedScalar(const ParsedScalar& other);
    ParsedScalar& operator= (const ParsedScalar& other);

public:
    const std::string& getName() const { return name; }
    Variant *getVariant() { return new V(sval, name); }

private:
    S sval;
    std::string name;

};
```

The S template parameter will be a scalar type (int, bool, double, etc.). The V template parameter will be the final variant class.

They are used like this:

```
ParsedVariant *functionA() {

    int n;
    // Some work here.
    return new ParsedScalar<int, IntegerVariant>(n, "varname");

}

void functionB() {

    ParsedVariant *var = functionA();
    // Do some work.
    delete var;    <== SEGV happens here.

}
```

The segfault occurs in the ParsedVariant destructor in the underlying call to free. It doesn't matter which scalar type I use in the template, they all segfault. The compiler is g++ 4.8.3, and I am using the -std=c++11 flag. I feel like this is something obvious, but I seem to be missing it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Cannot reproduce after adding code to make a complete program: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d06de612092e31c  The error is in code you didn't show.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the shown code, therefore the bug is in the code that's not shown. A [mcve] is required in order to determine the answer. Just because a C++ program crashed on one particular line doesn't mean that's where the bug is. Your bug can be anywhere. Welcome to C++...

Comment: What does your debugger say? Where is your [MCVE]? Basic stuff.

Comment: What is "do some work" and "some work here"?  If you did nothing and just issued calls to `new` and immediately call `delete` what are the results.

Comment: Until you provided the actually faulty code, just a remark: You should really refrain from returning newly created heap object pointers and manage their lifecycle externally. Consider some of the RAII-constructs of CPP (unique_ptr, shared_ptr, ...). This way you at least clear the code from all the new's and delete's and make it less errorprone

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem but the cause was very strange;

```
class ScalarParser {

    public: 
        ScalarParser();
       ~ScalarParser();

    public:
        ParsedVariant *getParsed() { return parsed; }
        void parse(std::istream& in); // Produces parsed

    private:
        ParsedVariant *parsed;
};

ScalarParser::~ScalarParser() {
    delete parsed;
}

void Document::parseScalar(std::istream& in) {

    ScalarParser parser;
    parser.parse(in);  <== produces valid ParsedVariant
    ParsedVariant *parsed = parser.getParsed(); <== ~ScalarParser called after this line
    push(parsed->getVariant()); <== SEGV

}
```

The segfault goes away if I comment out the delete in the ScalarParser destructor. This also makes the segfault go away.

```
void Document::parseScalar(std::istream& in) {

    ScalarParser *parser = new ScalarParser;
    parser->parse(in);
    ParsedVariant *parsed = parser->getParsed();
    push(parsed->getVariant());
    delete parser;

}
```

This also corrects the problem.

```
void Document::parseScalar(std::istream& in) {

    std::unique_ptr<ScalarParser> parser(new ScalarParser);
    parser->parse(in);
    ParsedVariant *parsed = parser->getParsed();
    push(parsed->getVariant());

}
```

This is a parser, so the code is large and convoluted. Some of it is also proprietary, so this is the best I can do. I'm not sure if this is a compiler bug. I'll keep poking at it for more information. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: *I'm not sure if this is a compiler bug* -- I bet it isn't a compiler bug.  A compiler would not be so faulty in such relatively simple code used in a large program.  A compiler does not get confused because the code is "large and convoluted".  A human being might be confused, but not the compiler.